# Alinhar imagem no rodape da janela do navegador

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como alinho uma imagem no rodape da janela do navegador, de forma que quando eu altero o tamanho da janela a imagem permaneça "encostada" no canto inferior da tela, sem ser cortada, segue abaixo meu andamento com o código, o emoji esta a direita da tela, porém quando eu ajusto a largura da janela do navegador o emoji fica la e fica oculto. O que eu estou tentando fazer é que a posicao dele seja corrigida automaticamente para que ele sempre fique encostado no abaixo da janela

Codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Posicionar um objeto na tela_2</title>
<style type="text/css">
#imgpos {
 position:absolute;
 left:100%;
 top:50%;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Para retornar ao tutorial use o bot&atilde;o &quot;Voltar&quot; do seu navegador.</p>
<img src="https://criemoda.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/sorriso.png" width="220" height="220" alt="logo maujor" id="imgpos">
</body>
</html>
```

Antecipadamente agradeço quem ler e puder responder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque no CSS da imagem:

```
{ 
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```